# How to remove zombie dwarves from Dwarf Therapist?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

After trying to fight off a zombie dingo with my melee militia, I've got a lot of zombies walking around outside my fortress. (Who'd have known it was contagious?)

For some reason, Dwarf Therapists lists zombie dwarves. Is there a way to remove them from the list, or sort the list by zombieness? It's kind of hard to get an overview of the fortress right now.

Comment: The simplest solution that comes to mind is to get rid of the zombies.

Comment: That would end up in all my dwarves being zombies. At least they'd be sorted.

Comment: Only if you use the least ingenious way of zombie extermination, which is force of arms. There are always traps, or you could just cavein the entire surface by 10 z-levels or so, that should get rid of most anything.

Answer (score 3):

When Dwarf Therapist picks up an illegitimate dwarf (mine shows a hostile captive were-beast and one dwarf who was kidnapped years ago) you could change their profession and nickname to something identifiable and unique.

Examples: ["nickname" name, PROFESSION]

- "VampireFace" McLastName, VAMPIRE
- "Wereskink" McLastName, ENEMY
- "zzSo-and-So" McLastName, DESCRIPTION

And so forth. It won't get rid of them, obviously, but it makes it easy to disregard their labor assignments when listing by profession and/or name. The last example would work exclusively to put them at the bottom of an alphabetical list, if you find yourself sorting that way most often. I put my custom profession names in all-caps to easily tell which ones I've made, but that isn't exactly necessary. =)